# SharePoint DateTimeControl not doing post back when the time is changed, it does when we change date

Tags: 2007, datepicker

I set SharePoint [DateTimeControl's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414993.aspx) autopostback property to true, but postback only works when I change the date, it doesn't work when I change time. any ideas to make it postback when the time is also changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTimeControl doesn't support autopostback for changing the time.