# Fire events on TIME changed in date picker

Tags: 2010, development, visual-web-part, datepicker

I am making a visual web part that has a date and time picker. Essentially, I would like the first of two date pickers to update the second date picker as long as the second one has not been modified by a user.

The event I have set up "onDateChanged" only seems to fire when a *date selection* is made, though. If a time is selected after the date, no event fires. Is there any way to trigger an event on the time being changed in addition to the date?

Comment: This question seems to indicate it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do, at least in 2007: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9185/sharepoint-datetimecontrol-not-doing-post-back-when-the-time-is-changed-it-does?rq=1

Is this the case for 2010? Is there a clever work-around that I'm missing?

Comment: trigger a postback with jQuery